# Is it possible to find 3 quadratic polynomials $f(x),g(x),h(x)$ such that $f(g(h(x))) = 0$ has 8 roots $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8$?

Tags: polynomials

Here is what I tried -
I assumed 3 quadratics $f(x) , g(x)$ and $h(x)$ with these I formed the gigantic equation $f(g(h(x)))$ it had a degree 8 therefore was satisfying the 8 degree criterion but I'm stuck at finding is it possible that it has roots $1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8.$

Comment: Thanks @YouKnowMe for the edit .

Comment: I suggest that you start by solving a simpler problem of the same type: find just $p$ and $q$ where $p(q(x))$ has the four roots $1,2,3,4$.

Comment: @MJD will this help me ?

Comment: I think it might.

Comment: Ok then i will try

Comment: But if anyone knows the solution please post it for some reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The polynomial $h$ must be $2$ to $1$ on the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.  Thus its stationary point must occur at $4.5$ (considering real and imaginary parts of $h$ separately).  Thus $$h(x)=a(x(9-x))+b,$$ and the values of $h$ applied to that set are $8a+b,14a+b,18a+b,20a+b$ for constants $a,b$.

By the same reasoning $g$ must be $2$ to $1$ on this set, so its stationary point must occur at $14a+b$ so that $g(8a+b)=g(20a+b)$.  However then $g(18a+b)\neq g(14a+b)$.  Thus we cannot have $3$ such quadratics.

Comment: What is a stationary point ?

Comment: @AdhirajSinghBrar It is where the derivative of the quadratic is $0$.  That is the minima or the maxima of the quadratic.  About this point the function is symmetric.

Comment: Ok and also one more thing what did u mean by h must be 2 to 1

Comment: @AdhirajSinghBrar As a quartic can have at most $4$ roots, $h(1),h(2),h(3,h(4),h(5),h(6),h(7),h(8)$ can take at most $4$ values.  As $h$ is a quadratic, no $3$ of these can be equal, so they must split up into $4$ pairs of equal values.

Comment: Oh ok got it Thanks